# Apt update failed because public key not available

Tags: apt

Please help, how do I fix this? I can't update because it just says for one of the entries: `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available`. How do I install the public key needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic error when using custom repositories. In order to fix, you need to run the following command:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys YOUR_KEY` where YOUR_KEY is replaced with the key you need, e.g: `8B48AD6246925553`.

There are also a number of other keyservers available if you'd prefer. For example, you could replace `keys.gnupg.net` with `keyserver.ubuntu.com` if you'd rather use Ubuntu's own keyserver, however this does not usually matter.

After running the command, then `sudo apt update` again, and it should work :)

Comment: `apt-key` is now deprecated, and the tool recommends managing keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead.

Comment: For older workloads where you still need to use these, I've found as of today that instead of `keys.gnupg.net` you can use `pgpkeys.mit.edu` and it worked fine.